# Any way to reduce output from Google Cloud Run emulator?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

The Google Cloud Run emulator (`gcloud beta code dev`) watches for file changes and rebuilds on every change.

So, in my terminal, there's a constant churn of building messages as I type, and it's distracting.

I tried (reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference)

- `--verbosity="none"` (no effect)
- `--quiet` just elminates interactivity.
- `--no-user-output-enabled` crashes the emulator with

```
Flag --enable-rpc has been deprecated, flags --rpc-port or --rpc-http-port now imply --enable-rpc=true, so please use only those instead
^CException in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
```

and a whole bunch more that I can copy if it matters.

**Is there a way to either silence build logs, but still get (1) my own console.logs and (2) errors?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* (because your question was the first time I became aware of this [useful] facility) that, because `gcloud beta code dev` is using (in my case) `minikube` (locally), the output is being generated by `minikube` (`kubelet`) process and **not** `gcloud`, that you can't (yet!) control the output by adding `gcloud` flags.

It's a good suggestion and I recommend you file an issue on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

`kubectl` (!) has a new configuration that points to `minikube` while it's running and (!) I'm able to `kubectl logs deployment/${APP}` from another term to view only my app's logs:

```sh
kubectl get deployments
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
${APP}    1/1     1            1           1m

kubectl logs deployment/${APP}
2022/01/06 17:21:58 Entered
2022/01/06 17:21:58 Starting server [:8080]
2022/01/06 17:21:58 Sleeping
2022/01/06 17:26:58 Awake
2022/01/06 17:26:58 Sleeping
```

`~/.kube/config`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /path/to/.minikube/ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 06 Jan 2022 09:21:47 PST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.24.0
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.49.2:8443
  name: gcloud-local-dev
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gcloud-local-dev
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 06 Jan 2022 09:21:47 PST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.24.0
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: gcloud-local-dev
  name: gcloud-local-dev
current-context: gcloud-local-dev
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gcloud-local-dev
  user:
    client-certificate: /path/to/.minikube/profiles/gcloud-local-dev/client.crt
    client-key: /path/to/.minikube/profiles/gcloud-local-dev/client.key
```